# why can't use constexpr if (expression) , even the expression can be evaluated at compile time

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr

```
//code1
class Test {
public:
  constexpr Test(const char *p) : p_(p) {}
  constexpr int foo() const 
  {
    if(p_[0] != 'a')
      return 1;
    else
      return 2;
  }
  const char *p_;
};

int arr[Test("bbb").foo()];  //this works
```

why the following code not work?

```
  //code2
  constexpr int foo() const 
  {
    constexpr if (p_[0] != 'a') //add constexpr
      return 1;
    else
      return 2;
  }
```

Got an error:

> error: expected unqualified-id before ‘if’

To my understanding, since "`p_[0] != 'a'`" can be evaluated at compile time(as shown in code1),  so `constexpr if (p_[0] != 'a')`  should be a valid statement which can be evaluate during compiling.

Comment: Pretend that you are a compiler. Can you compute what the value of the expression `p_[0] != 'a'` is? Full stop. Do not pass "Go". Do not collect $200 until you prove what the value of this expression is. At compile time. So you can replace that entire expression with a single value, and it has to be either true, or false. Unless you can answer this question this cannot be a `constexpr`. Because that's what it is, by definition. A constant expression. A constant. The End.

Comment: Syntax error, it must be `if constexpr`, not `constexpr if`!

Comment: @barry Actually that isn't bad.  The one that works, you can map it to `2` at compile time.  The one that does not, if you say "well `false`", then replace the condition *with* `false`, you can quickly see how that isn't right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To my understanding, since "`p_[0] != 'a'`" can be evaluated at compile time(as shown in code1), so `constexpr if (p_[0] != 'a')` should be a valid statement which can be evaluate during compiling.

`p_[0] != 'a'` **can** be evaluated compile-time but can also be evaluated run-time.

The problem is that a `if constexpr` test **must** be evaluated compile-time. And this is impossible when `foo()` is executed run-time or when the corresponding `Test` object is initialized run-time.

So the error.

Or better: the error if you write correctly

```
if constexpr (p_[0] != 'a')
```

In your case the order between `if` and `constexpr` is also wrong.